# HTTP and HTTPS causes redirection Loop

Tags: http, https, cas

I am making one Central Authentication server module (CAS). For that I am configuring web.config file. Since I have to integrate it with other Applications I don't want to write any code in code behind file. The configurations are
OS - Windows 7
IIS 7
Visual Studio 2005.

The server which hosts the cas application has the login page which authenticates the user. I am able to redirect to the cas login page at first time.

My problem is that I am not able to redirect to my own application page which is default.aspx hosted on my PC. The CAS server runs linux os and I am using Windows 7. I am getting redirect loop and after login from cas login module, I am not able to see my page. Firefox shows "waiting for servername" and "waiting for hostname" in status bar continuously. Can any body help me in solving this problem??? I am badly stuck here and very desperate to come out of this as soon as possible.
I am using form authentication mode in web.config. Or is it the problem with HTTP and HTTPS?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like the windows machines is not seeing the session as authenticated, but the CAS is seeing the session as authenticated. Therefore windows redirects to linux, which redirects to windows, which redirects to linux....

I think you see the picture.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but What is the solution? Do I need to develop this on linux machine or on any windows server? can there be any certificate related error? since as I write HTTP infront of my localhost it goes in infinite loop and when I write HTTPS firefox shows an error. I do have a certificate exported from IE but it does not contain private key.

Comment: Got it!!!! It was a matter of installing the certificates at a particular place, in trusted root authorities. Now it works Perfect!!!